# Tomcat 7.0.23 & Spring 3.1 & task scheduler multiple invocations

Tags: spring, task, scheduled-tasks

my spring.xml looks like

```
<task:scheduler id="feedServiceScheduler"  pool-size="10"/>
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="feedServiceScheduler">        


    <task:scheduled ref="feedService" method="testMethod" cron="0 50 11 * * *" />

</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

I expect method "testMethod" to be invoked on object "feedService" at 11:50 every day of the year
For some reason testMethod is invoked twice and I just can't find a solution to the problem.

"feedService" bean is nothing fancy, just a simple POJO and test method prints out a message.

Any help about what I might be doing wrong would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Did you load that configuration twice? (app-context vs. web-context)?

Comment: I only declare the spring servlet in web.xml and along with that I have a log4jlistener and org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. As it seems, tomcat creates multiple servlet instances, so scheduled procs are scheduled multiple times so.

Here is a little log, where you can see the runs initiated on different classes:

```
[2012-03-22 11:03:00,001] [ClickCheatReportGenerator] DEBUG ClickCheatersender called (com.innofeed.mindenkupon.schedules.ClickCheatReportGenerator@5238d01c)

[2012-03-22 11:03:00,004] [ClickCheatReportGenerator] DEBUG ClickCheatersender called (com.innofeed.mindenkupon.schedules.ClickCheatReportGenerator@fe70870)

[2012-03-22 11:03:00,004] [ClickCheatReportGenerator] DEBUG ClickCheatersender called (com.innofeed.mindenkupon.schedules.ClickCheatReportGenerator@8daf938)
```

You should limit tomcat to run only 1 servlet instance, but maybe that will cause performance issues.

**Update:**
Finally solved the problem using cron schedules calling for urls handled by controllers.